# Convert GenBank Nucleotide Accession to Gene Symbol

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a list of GenBank Nucleotide Accessions like this:

```
>list
NM_144958
NM_144959
NM_144960
NM_144961
NM_144962
NM_144963
XM_006539402
```

and I want to convert them to their own Gene Symbols using Biomart, I tried this

```
ensembl = useMart(biomart = "ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL",
              dataset="mmusculus_gene_ensembl", 
              host = "www.ensembl.org")

convert.fun<-function(x){
  getBM(attributes="external_gene_name", values = x, mart=ensembl )

}

convert<-apply(list,1,FUN=convert.fun)
```

It returns me a list that contains the same names and numbers in each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"external_gene_name"` attribute needs to be filtered by the values that you have. Your values are RefSeq RNA identifiers, so you'd like to use the filter `"refseq_mrna"`. `getBM()` is vectorized, so works on all the gene identifiers at once, so create a character vector (I'm not sure what `list` is, I think you edited the output above), e.g.,

```
values = c("NM_144958", "NM_144959", "NM_144960")
```

and use them

```
getBM(c("refseq_mrna", "external_gene_name"), "refseq_mrna", values,
      mart=ensembl)
```

(the first argument returns the query as well as the identifiers, which helps when there are 1:0 or 1:many mappings, as for the second identifier).

```
>     getBM(c("refseq_mrna", "external_gene_name"), "refseq_mrna", values,
+           mart=ensembl)
  refseq_mrna external_gene_name
1   NM_144958             Eif4a1
2   NM_144960              Fcamr
```

Either [biostars](https://biostars.org) or the [Bioconductor support forum](https://support.bioconductor.org) would be more appropriate forums for this type of question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer and just another question ,  Does "external_gene_name" give me gene symbols? @Martin

Comment: That's the kind of question someone on the biostars or bioc support site would be able to answer! But I think the answer is yes.